# How to compare page views/visitors to site totals in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to measure the effects in total traffic (views or visitors) of a single URL across a time frame.

For example, let's say I published a blog post on July 2012. I want to measure what chunk of the site's total traffic is coming to this particular post on a month-by-month graph from July 2012 to date.

Is there a way to do this?

**Edit:** I should clarify that what I'd like to do is to generate a month-to-month *graph*, similar to the one you can see comparing a metric on a period of time against the previous equivalent period (year vs last year, for example) but comparing a particular URL traffic to the site's total traffic.

In other words, I can get to the part where I can see the URL's traffic for the timeframe I selected and it shows how much of the total traffic corresponds to the current URL:

[image: Pageviews for a particular URL]

But I'd like to add a second line to the graph, representing the site's total pageviews, similiar to this (but this one is showing just a different metric for the same URL):

[image: Pageviews vs Bounce Rate for a particular URL, but can I compare against site's total pageviews? *cue mistery music*]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple, Just got to `Content` on Left Sidebar and under it search `All Pages` in `Site Content`. Now you 'll see statistics of most popular pages/posts of your blog. You can search for your post using search option in it and by clicking on the blog post, You 'll see reporting of that blog post only. Select Date of the reporting from July 2012 to today's date (At top-right) and for monthly reporting there is an option on the right hand site of the graph to view the graph as week, month and year.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! I'm trying to get this information in a graph. I edited the question with some more details. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date selector and check reporting of every week/month of your site. In the head (right side) of the Analytics site you have the Date Picker.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question with more details of what I want to achieve. Cheers!